# How to render links in unsafe String [gwt]

Tags: java, html, gwt

I was wondering how it is possible to achieve the following behavior:

assume you have a String like this

```
String message = <a href="www.stackoverflow.com">stackoverflow</a>`
```

as part of a message to be displayed in a GWT template

```
@SafeHtmlTemplates.Template("<div>{0}</div>")
SafeHtml postMessage(String message);
```

This is interpreted as text and not as HTML as supposed. But I want to have the `www.stackoverflow.com` as a clickable link in this plain text. The result should look like the image below

[image]

the URL should be treated as SafeHtml whereas everything else should be treated as plain text. 
I know how to use SafeHtmlUtils to build SafeHtml but not how to get an unknown amount of SafeHtml links within an unsafe String ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    String s1 = SafeHtmlUtils.htmlEscape("<a href=\"");
    String s2 = "<a href=\"www.stackoverflow.com\">stackoverflow</a>";
    String s3 = SafeHtmlUtils.htmlEscape("\">stackoverflow</a>");

    SafeHtml html=SafeHtmlUtils.fromTrustedString(s1+s2+s3);
```

I have done this and got [image: Output]

Comment: thank you, I don't had a clue. to make this more generic it's possible to htmlEscape the String and use regexp to frame the URL in the resulting String with the HTML markup